# Error when Building GPU docker image for caffe: Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_60'

Tags: macos, docker, caffe

An attempt to build the *gpu* based `caffe` docker image was unsuccessful. The command run:

```
docker build -t caffe:gpu standalone/gpu
```

It ran for about twenty minutes including compiling many numpy/scikit scripts to c-code via `cython`.   However the build finally failed in an nvidia `nvcc` step:

```
[  1%] [  1%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_generated_cudnn_pooling_layer.cu.o
Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/util/./cuda_compile_generated_im2col.cu.o
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_60'
CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_cudnn_pooling_layer.cu.o.cmake:206 (message):
  Error generating
  /opt/caffe/build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_generated_cudnn_pooling_layer.cu.o


make[2]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_generated_cudnn_pooling_layer.cu.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_60'
CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_im2col.cu.o.cmake:206 (message):
  Error generating

/opt/caffe/build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/util/./cuda_compile_generated_im2col.cu.o


make[2]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/util/./cuda_compile_generated_im2col.cu.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am on `El Capitan` and running on a late 2013 MBPro that has the `GT750m` nvidia chipset.

Note: The ***cpu*** based `caffe` docker image from their github repo: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe `docker` was successfully built inside the `caffe/docker` directory on my mac:

```
docker build -t caffe:cpu standalone/cpu
```

.. and about ten minutes later ..

```
Successfully built bf71c19501e5
```

There is some mention of a different project `arrayfire` encountering similar error  https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire/issues/1535 .  However I lack the specific knowledge to troubleshoot the `BVLC/caffe/docker` commands to try to replicate what appears to be `cuda7.5` vs `cuda8.0` versioning issues.

Has anyone successfully built the ***gpu*** version of Caffe on docker container from mac?

Comment: running into the same problem on a linux x86_64 server

Comment: Same problem on Ubuntu 14.04 nvidia-docker x86_64 server.

Comment: Same problem on Ubuntu 14.04 nvidia-docker x86_64 server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Makefile.example, try commenting out the *_60 and *_61 lines (for compatibility with CUDA < 8.0).

```
CUDA_ARCH := -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 \
        -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 \
        -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
        -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
        -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
        -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 \
        #-gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 \
        #-gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 \
        #-gencode arch=compute_61,code=compute_61
```